# Extract numbers only from the strings in which a keyword is mentioned

Tags: python, arrays, string, if-statement, filter

I have 4 elements stored in an array, I want to get the integers only from the strings in which **Approved** key word is mentioned.

```
my_array = ['STK72184 4/28/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 50 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus 25000 Regular 10/20/2023 Approved 4/28/2022',
            'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 5000 Regular 10/19/2023 Closed 4/27/2022',
            'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 15000 Regular 10/19/2023 Closed 4/27/2022',
            'STK722222 4/26/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 10000 Regular 10/18/2023 Approved 4/26/2022']
```

Till now I can only get the integers from the list by doing this:

```
import re

# Print integers
nums = [int(re.search(r'\d+000', s)[0]) for s in my_array]
print(nums)

# Printed output:
# [25000, 5000, 15000, 10000]
```

Expected output is:

```
[25000,10000]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and an `if`. Note that the second example shows that regex-based search can be quite powerful in pulling out just the patterns you want, thus I almost always prefer it to exact string match (except when performance is critical). Also, I renamed `array` to `lst` (this data structure is called list in Python, and array is some other languages).

```
import re

my_lst = ['STK72184 4/28/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 50 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus 25000 Regular 10/20/2023 Approved 4/28/2022',
          'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 5000 Regular 10/19/2023 Closed 4/27/2022',
          'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 15000 Regular 10/19/2023 Closed 4/27/2022',
          'STK722222 4/26/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 10000 Regular 10/18/2023 Approved 4/26/2022']

nums = [int(re.search(r'\d+000', s)[0]) for s in my_lst if re.search(r'Approved', s)]
print(nums)
# [25000, 10000]

nums = [int(re.search(r'\d+000', s)[0]) for s in my_lst if re.search(r'4/2[67]', s)]
print(nums)
# [5000, 15000, 10000]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_array = ['STK72184 4/28/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 50 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus 25000 Regular 10/20/2023 Approved 4/28/2022',
            'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 5000 Regular 10/19/2023 Closed 4/27/2022',
            'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 15000 Regular 10/19/2023 Closed 4/27/2022',
            'STK722222 4/26/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 10000 Regular 10/18/2023 Approved 4/26/2022']

import re

# Print integers
nums = [int(re.search(r'\d+000', s)[0]) for s in my_array if 'Approved' in s]
print(nums) # [25000, 10000]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter for the desired numbers without re. Simply use `next()` function to search for the desired number. This assumed that there is an integer that ends with "000"s in each element in `my_array` (this assumption is also made in your original code, so I assume it's OK).

```py
# search a string that ends with '000' among the words in each element that includes "Approved" in my_array
[int(next(i for i in s.split() if i[-3:]=='000')) for s in my_array if 'Approved' in s]
# [25000, 10000]
```